# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'insert_query' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm making a login page code on Python (with Tkinter) that creates a database table where the users' id and the time they logged in are registered whenever a user succesfully logs in. However, everytime I run it, I keep getting the same error, and I'm not sure if it's because I'm using "Try Except" incorrectly or the way I'm inserting the foreign primery key in cur.execute(insert_query, ...) Here's the block of code of the .py file that I worked on where I'm encountering the most issues:

```
def login():
if idEntry.get() == '' or passwdEntry.get() == '':
    messagebox.showerror('Alert', 'Please enter all entry fields!')
else:
    db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='Orlando1208', database='testP')
    cur = db.cursor()
    query = 'select * from personaldata where passwrd=%s'
    cur.execute(query, (passwdEntry.get(),))
    roles = cur.fetchone()

    if roles == None:
        messagebox.showerror('Alert!', 'Incorrect username or password')
        return
    
    else:
        try:
            queryActi = 'use testP'
            cur.execute(queryActi)
            queryActi='create table if not exists Registro_Actividad (userId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,fecha DATETIME,FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES personaldata(id)) ' \
            
            cur.execute(queryActi)
        except: 
            loginTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            cur.execute('use testP')
            insert_query = 'insert into Registro_Actividad (userId, fecha) VALUES (%s, %s)'
            last_id = cur.lastrowid
        cur.execute(insert_query, (last_id,) + loginTime)
        db.commit()
        db.close
        messagebox.showinfo('success', 'Login Successful')
        # clear screen
        idEntry.delete(0, END)
        passwdEntry.delete(0, END)
        main_running = False
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            if 'Mainwin.py' in proc.name():
                main_running = True
                break

        if not main_running:
            subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Mainwin.py'])
            windows.destroy()
```

An advice on how to fix this?